# Node Lambda timing out firebase-admin SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications through Firebase Cloud Messaging from a node js lambda in AWS.

My function works and I receive the notification on my phone, however the lambda keeps timing out (even at 20s timeout). I can see in logs my lambda callback is being called. It appears that something is preventing the lambda from returning.

I initialise with:

```js
const serviceAccount = require('./firebaseKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'xxx',
});
```

and send with:

```js
const fcmResponse = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, message);
```

My hunch is that it's something here preventing it from returning as everything else is pretty vanilla.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's causing the timeouts?

Comment: Are you able to show more of your code? Are you doing anything with the `fcmResponse` value? I am guessing you aren't returning a promise to the function and it doesn't know when things end. Just a guess without seeing more of the function code.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking at this.

Firebase seems to leave some stuff kicking around, which means the callback is never called.

Adding the following line in the handler solves the problem:

```js
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```